# Propagating 'typedef' from based to derived class for 'template'

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef, name-lookup

I'm trying to define base class, which contains typedef's only.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> Vec_t;
};


template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
private:
    Vec_t v;  // fails - Vec_t is not recognized
};
```

Why in B I receive an error that Vec_t is not recognized and I need to write it explicitly?

```
typename A<T>::Vec_t v;
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible

Comment: Well, not really an exact duplicate since the post you mention talks about a method while this one talks about a type.

Comment: typename A::Vec_t v; is fine. No need for <T> there

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I believe that this question is duplicate, but I cannot find it now. C++ Standard says that you should fully qualify name according to 14.6.2/3:

> In the definition of a class template or a member of a class template, if a base class of the class template depends on a template-parameter, the **base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup** either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

**UPD:** I found duplicate finally: [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible).

Comment: By the way, it always bug me that I had to 're-typedef' everything... it's not pleasant, not pleasant at all.

Comment: btw you don't need all the template arguments and all, when qualifying. Because of the injected class name, it suffices to write `typename B::Vec_t`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm trying to do it as you said, but I'm getting errors if I don't specify the template parameters for B. (B is not a class, namespace, 
 or enumeration)

Comment: @GonzaloSolera I am having your same error result, but only on one of my platforms, one with an older C++ standard. I wonder if the need to fully qualify changed at some point?

Answer (score 43):

There is something called dependent and *nondependent* names in case of templates.

If name depends on template parameter T its *dependent* name and others those do not depend on parameter T are *independent* names.

> Here's the rule: the compiler does not
>   look in dependent base classes (like
>   A) when looking up nondependent
>   names (like Vec_t). As a result,
>   the compiler does not know they even
>   exist let alone are types.

Compiler cannot assume that `Vec_t` is a type until it knows `T` because There is a potential specialization of `A<T>` where `A<T>:: Vec_t` is a is a data member

So the solution is use typename

```
 typename A<T>::Vec_t v;  ← good
```

I recommend you go through this https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types.

Old (broken) link: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18

Comment: Yours was the only answer that seemed to provide a solution in addition to an explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I offer you a +1 if you notify me that you have corrected the link.

Answer (score 10):

For completeness, here's how you could mitigate this nuisance a little, either:

- re-typedef those types in derived classes, or better - as with
  methods -
- just import those names in the derived class scope with a `using declaration`:

---

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> Vec_t;
};


template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    using typename A<T>::Vec_t;
    // .........

private:
    Vec_t v;
};
```

It can be useful if you have more than one mentioning of the inherited `typedef` in the derived class. Also you don't need to add `typename` each time with this.

Comment: You have a typo.  `using typename A::Vec_t;` should be `using typename A<T>::Vec_t;`

Answer (score 8):

Because the compiler's not certain that `Vec_t` names a type. For example, `A<T>` might be specialized for `T=int` to *not* have that particular `typedef`.

Comment: For `T` a type variable, `A<T>` is merely forward declared, it does not have a definition. Only `A<t>` where `t` is a type (not type variable) can be defined (by specializing a template definition or by an explicit specialisation). IOW, even if you removed template explicit and partial specialisations from C++ (and but not change anything else), it still would not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly qualify the use of `Vec_t` because the compiler does not know where `Vec_t` comes from.

It cannot assume anything about the structure of A, since the class template A may be specialized. The specialization may include a `Vec_t` which is not a typedef, or it may not even include a member `Vec_t` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Vec_t is not a dependent name, and the compiler needs to know what it is without instantiating any templates (base class in this case). It is really no different from:

```
template <class T>
class X
{
    std::string s;
}
```

Here as well the compiler needs to know about std::string even if X is not instantiated, since the name does not depend on the template argument T (as far as the compiler can assume).

All in all, typedefs in a template base class seem rather useless for use in derived class. The typedefs are useful for the user, however.

Comment: do you mean `class X : T {` here?

Answer (score 1):

This concept can be associated with how we use `std::vector<T>`. For example, if we have a `std::vector<int> Foo`. Now, we decide to use any of it's member types, lets say an `iterator`. In this scenario we explicitly mention

```
std::vector<int>::iterator foo_iterator;
```

Similarly in your case, in order to use a public member type `Vec_t` of `template <typename T> class A`, you need to explicitly declare it as

```
A<T>::Vec_t v;
OR
A<int>::Vec_t int_type;
```