# STL copy failed on array of 'typedef' type

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

Platform: MinGW64 (rubenvb 4.7.2), Windows 7 (64), Qt 4.8.2

Given code segment as follow:

```
/* type definition */
typedef long T_PSIZE;
struct A { T_PSIZE myArray[10]; };
struct B { T_PSIZE myArray[10]; };
/* declare variable */
A a;
B b;
std::copy(a.myArray[0], a.myArray[10], &b.myArray);
```

I don't know why the compiler throws the following error messages (similar messages also shown when changed from 'typedef long T_PSIZE;' to 'typedef int T_PSIZE;'):

```
> c:\mingw\rubenvb-4.7.2-64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:
> In instantiation of '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool
> _IsMove = false; _II = long int; _OI = long int (*)[9]]': c:\mingw\rubenvb-4.7.2-64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:422:39:
> required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool
> _IsMove = false; _II = long int; _OI = long int (*)[9]]' c:\mingw\rubenvb-4.7.2-64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:454:18:
> required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = long int; _OI
> = long int (*)[9]]' ..\InfluSimHKPrototype\SimApplication.cpp:114:36:   required from here
> c:\mingw\rubenvb-4.7.2-64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:375:57:
> error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<long
> int>'
> c:\mingw\rubenvb-4.7.2-64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:377:64:
> error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct
> std::iterator_traits<long int>'
> c:\mingw\rubenvb-4.7.2-64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:381:57:
> error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<long
> int>'
> c:\mingw\rubenvb-4.7.2-64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:384:70:
> error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct
> std::iterator_traits<long int>'
```

It seems that the type 'long int' cannot be recognized by the compiler's template engine. I used the similar statement with array of 'ordinary int' and it works great. I'm not using any STL containers as I know exactly the size of the target array, so I don't think I need to re-implement something like back_inserter. Do I missed something?

**Note**: I'm not sure if the question [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template/1643190#1643190) help. (Or how can I can get the 'full' qualified name for the statement to work on typedef-ed variables?)

Comment: I'm surprised to see `_OI = long int (*)[9]` in the error message. Does the error match the code which you are actually using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
std::copy(&a.myArray[0], &a.myArray[10], &b.myArray[0]);
```

or

```
std::copy(a.myArray, a.myArray + 10, b.myArray);
```

`a.myArray[0]` is just a `long`, not a pointer *into* an array of `long` which `std::copy` requires. Also, the type of the output parameter needs to be compatible with the type of the object being copied. `&b.myArray` has type `long (*)[10]` whereas you need to supply a parameter of type `long*`.