# Template dependent inherited typedefs and MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

A few weeks ago I wrote a trait class for 2d entities like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct traits_2d
{
    typedef T coordinates_type;
    typedef vector_2d<T> position_type;
    typedef vector_2d<T> direction_type;
    typedef vector_2d<T> size_type;
};
```

The trait class was used as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct aabb_2d : public traits_2d<T>
{
    position_type origin;
    size_type size;
};
```

The Standard says that template dependent names must be fully qualified, so this should not compile. Of course GCC compilation fails and says something like:

> Expected nested-name specifier. Could be '`typename traits_2d<T>::position_type`'.

But, on the other hand, I was using this pattern for two weeks in MSVC11 (Visual Studio 2012) and it works and compiles fine.

Why seems like MSVC11 does not follow this language rule?

**NOTE:** This question is not a duplicate of [Propagating 'typedef' from based to derived class for 'template'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template) or its duplicates, it asks about why something that should be an error works in MSVC.

Comment: Multiple duplicates... VS does not correctly implement two phase lookup, and does not require the use of `typename` there. That is an *extension* (to give it a name) that will be fixed somewhere in the future

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas thanks a lot. So, as I thought before, MSVC sucks. If you post that as an answer I would accept it.