# Inherit trait typedefs from a standard container

Tags: c++

Without inheriting from vector, how do I get all of its typedefs?

```
template <typename T>
class MyStack
{
public:
    typename std::vector<T>::reference top()
    {
        return storage.front();
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> storage;
};
```

`std::vector<T>::reference` is too much typing. I'm looking for something like iterator category except for containers instead of iterators. But I heard you're not allowed to inherit from standard containers.

Comment: About my answer, I think the problem arises because the compiler cannot prove that every `std::vector<T>` contains the nested type `reference` (e.g., there could be a separate translation unit that specializes `std::vector` to not have one and this translation unit cannot possibly have knowledge of that when compiled in isolation). I'm not sure what governs the difference between using `reference` and `typename container_type_aliases<std::vector<T>>::reference` that causes the latter to work. Something involving dependent vs. nondependent name lookup.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template. So, my technique will work in general, but not for classes that derive from a use of it that depends on a template parameter. (Also, I should have said qualified vs. unqualified name lookup)

Answer (score 0):

Use `typedef` to make it shorter

```
typedef std::vector<T>::reference brief_t;
```

**EDITED**
You can inherit from `std::` container but it is not recomended for reasons from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110262/149818. Just to make record shorter pick one of the ways:

- as my one above;
- make `typedef std::vector<T> super_t` and use `super_t::reference`;
- if you need just pick specific result of member use `decltype`: `typedef typename decltype( std::vector<T>().size() ) mysize_t;`

Comment: I still have to manually get the type defs. I want them inherited automatically.