# Friend class, inheritance and typedef -- which behavior is correct?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I've stumbled upon an error which manifestates itself only on GCC 6.2.0, but not on Clang 3.9.0 (both in `-std=c++14` mode). I'm unsure which behavior is correct (and whether I should file a bug).

Here's the code:

```cpp
template<typename type_t>
class foo_t
{
};

class bar_t
{
public:
    using foo_t = int;
};

class baz_t:
    public bar_t
{
private:
    template<typename type_t>
    friend class foo_t;
};
```

On GCC this gives the following error:

```
test.cpp:17:15: error: using typedef-name ‘using foo_t = int’ after ‘class’
  friend class foo_t;
               ^~~~~
test.cpp:9:19: note: ‘using foo_t = int’ has a previous declaration here
  using foo_t = int;
                   ^
```

From what I know of C++ standard, parent `typedef`'s (or `using`s) should not leak into scope of the child and you need to explicitly qualify the name: see for example [Propagating 'typedef' from based to derived class for 'template'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template). So it seems to me that GCC is incorrect here, but I'm not so sure of my C++ knowledge to say with confidence.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Interesting workaround: `friend class ::foo_t` works.

Comment: It is because `::foo_t` means the global scope. if no `::`, the compiler intereput the closest scope as possible

Comment: In case someone is interested -- I've filed a bug about ICE with my new example with the workaround applied at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77869

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I know of C++ standard, parent `typedef`'s (or `using`s) should not leak into scope of the child and you need to explicitly qualify the name

That is incorrect. Members (including type aliases) declared in base classes are visible in derived classes normally. The question you linked to specifically deals with templates with a dependent base class, where two-phase name lookup applies (and again, applies to everything, not just type aliases).

This aside, the relevant part of the standard is C++14 (N4140) [dcl.type.elab] 7.1.6.3/2 (emphasis mine):

> 3.4.4 describes how name lookup proceeds for the *identifier* in an *elaborated-type-specifier.* If the *identifier*
>   resolves to a *class-name* or *enum-name,* the *elaborated-type-specifier* introduces it into the declaration the
>   same way a *simple-type-specifier* introduces its *type-name.* **If the *identifier* resolves to a *typedef-name* or
>   the *simple-template-id* resolves to an alias template specialization, the *elaborated-type-specifier* is ill-formed.**

(Note: *elaborated-type-specifier* is the construct `class T` for some `T` that we're dealing with).

3.4.4, in turn, says that when resolving the identifier in an elaborated-type-specifier into a name, non-type names are ignored (but type names are found normally).

GCC is therefore actually right, since the typedef-name `foo_t` in scope `bar_t` is "closer" in scope than the global-scope template-name `foo_t`. The unqualified name `foo_t` inside `baz_t` therefore resolves to `bar_t::foo_t`, which is a *typedef-name* and therefore makes the elaborated-type-specifier ill-formed.

The problem is with the resolution of the **unqualified** name `foo_t`. As you note yourself in comments to the question, explicitly stating which `foo_t` you mean should solve the issue:

```
tempalte <typename type_t>
friend class ::foo_t;
```

Comment: Aha, I got the part about depended base classes now, thanks (I've actually mostly encountered those lately and incorrectly extrapolated their behaviour).

Comment: However, I'm not sure I understand the second part -- why is elaborated specifier prevents from using this `typedef`? (this was supposed to go into the first comment initially, sorry)

Comment: @NikolayAmiantov Sorry, I re-worded the answer significantly (basically rewrote the second part from scratch). Can you see whether your question still applies?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately, this workaround probuces an GCC ICE for me on an original code (I'll need to isolate example anew). Either way, I understood what the problem is with my example. I'll mark your  answer as accepted because you were the first and explained what's going on elaborately.

Comment: so did anyone file a clang bug?

Comment: I'm in the process of doing so -- they require requesting a bugtracker account manually via e-mail. I've sent it yesterday but still received no reply... Will post a link when done.

Answer (score 1):

Members' declaration DO visible to its subclass. The problem for your question is about duplicate declaration. Please check the following code

```
template<typename type_t>
class foo_t
{
};

class bar_t
{
public:
    using foo_t = int;
};

class baz_t :
    public bar_t
{
public:
    foo_t val; // Here, the foo_t refers to the int
};

int main()
{
    baz_t().val; // this works
}
```

The error code you post `test.cpp:9:19: note: ‘using foo_t = int’ has a previous declaration here` already mentioned this problem.

---

On the other hands, friend class cannot be applied to simple data type, please check the following code:

```
using foo_t = int;

class bar_t
{
public:

};

class baz_t :
    public bar_t
{
public:
    template<typename type_t>
    friend class foo_t; 
    //error: using typedef-name ‘using foo_t = int’ after ‘class’
};
```

---

Here is the workaround if you really need to have the duplicated name of declaration:

```
template<typename type_t>
class foo_t
{
};

class bar_t
{
public:
    using foo_t = int;
};

class baz_t:
    public bar_t
{
public:
    template<typename type_t>
    friend class ::foo_t;   // The global scope

    foo_t val; // The int
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've specified `int` just as an example to show the problem, but the description was helpful anyway. I have a more pressing issue now, though (see the comment above) and will need some time to get the gist of it ~_^.