# C++ template class inherit

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, name-lookup

how to define a template class inherit from template class ?

I want to wrap `std::queue` and `std::priority_queue` to a base class. In my case is `LooperQueue`.
I use `StdQueue` in this way `auto queue = new StdQueue<LooperMessage *>()`.

my class define compiler complain

**error log:**

```
  In file included from /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/src/main/cpp/Painter.cpp:10:
  /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/src/main/cpp/util/StdQueue.h:14:5: error: unknown type name 'size_type'; did you mean 'size_t'?
      size_type size() override;
      ^~~~~~~~~
      size_t
  /Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/5.0.300080/include/stddef.h:62:23: note: 'size_t' declared here
  typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
                        ^
  In file included from /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/src/main/cpp/Painter.cpp:10:
  /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/src/main/cpp/util/StdQueue.h:16:5: error: unknown type name 'reference'
      reference front() override;
      ^
  /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/src/main/cpp/util/StdQueue.h:20:21: error: unknown type name 'value_type'; did you mean 'ARect::value_type'?
      void push(const value_type &x) override;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
                      ARect::value_type
  /Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/android/rect.h:44:21: note: 'ARect::value_type' declared here
      typedef int32_t value_type;
```

**code:**

```cpp
#ifndef PBOTEST_LOOPERQUEUE_H
#define PBOTEST_LOOPERQUEUE_H

#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename Tp, typename Sequence = std::deque<Tp> >
class LooperQueue {
  public:

    typedef typename Sequence::value_type                value_type;
    typedef typename Sequence::reference                 reference;
    typedef typename Sequence::const_reference           const_reference;
    typedef typename Sequence::size_type                 size_type;
    typedef          Sequence                            container_type;


    virtual size_type size()  = 0;

    virtual reference front() = 0;

    virtual void pop()= 0;

    virtual void push(const value_type &x) = 0;
};

#endif //PBOTEST_LOOPERQUEUE_H
```

```cpp
#ifndef PBOTEST_STDQUEUE_H
#define PBOTEST_STDQUEUE_H

#include "LooperQueue.h"

template<typename Tp, typename Sequence = std::deque<Tp> >
class StdQueue : public LooperQueue<Tp, Sequence> {
  public:
    size_type size() override;

    reference front() override;

    void pop() override;

    void push(const value_type &x) override;
    
  private:
    std::queue<Tp, Sequence> mQueue;
};

#endif //PBOTEST_STDQUEUE_H
```

Comment: posting compiler errors without filenames and line numbers stinks.  Also, I recommend using 'using' instead of typedef.  The syntax is more clear and I think it can give better error messages sometimes, too.

Comment: Also, you are not allowed to use names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter, or any name starting with two underscores.   _Sequence, for example, is not allowed.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/493106

Comment: @xaxxon any identifier with two consecutive underscores *anywhere* in it is not allowed

Comment: @xaxxon sorry about my error log post . I removed underscores, but error remain same.  I don't understand about  "`using` instead of typedef".  is there more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the base class `LooperQueue` is a dependent base class, which depends on the template parameter `Tp` and `Sequence`, then its complete type can't be determined without knowing the template arguments. Standard C++ says that nondependent names (like `size_type`, `reference` and `value_type`) won't be looked up in dependent base classes.

To correct the code, it suffices to make the names qualified by the base class name; then these names can be looked up only at the time of instantiation, and at that time the exact base specialization that must be explored will be known. e.g.

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Sequence = std::deque<_Tp> >
class StdQueue : public LooperQueue<_Tp, _Sequence> {
public:
    typename LooperQueue<_Tp, _Sequence>::::size_type size() override;
    typename LooperQueue<_Tp, _Sequence>::reference front() override;
    void pop() override;
    void push(const typename LooperQueue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type &__x) override;
private:
    std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence> mQueue;
};
```

Comment: can I define `StdQueue` in `*.h` file and implement `StdQueue` in `*.cpp` file ?

Comment: @Fantasy_RQG See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790)

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to use a simpler example that gives you the same error, consider a base with just one alias defined and a subclass that tries to use it:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
 public:
  using value_type = T;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
  value_type func();  // error
};
```

Because of the crazy nature of templates, the compiler can't know what `value_type` is at this point.  You have to tell it that it comes from the Base class either by qualifying it:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
  typename Base<T>::value_type func();
};
```

or telling the compiler with a `using` declaration that you are intending to use a base class type alias

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
  using typename Base<T>::value_type;
  value_type func();
};
```

The compiler can't actually know that `Base<T>` contains a `value_type` until it knows what `T` is and instantiates the template. *Why can't it just look at the Base template?* -- such a thing would be theoretically possible, but it doesn't know what specializations will be available.  If somewhere else you had

```
template<>
class Base<int> {};
```

Then `Derived<int>` would have to look for `value_type` elsewhere in its scope, and that's what it does in your original code. It tries to find a `value_type` and fails. This behavior can lead to some surprising results:

```
using value_type = char;
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
  value_type func(); // this is the global value_type = char, always
};
```

For a more ground-up explanation on related topics [you can read my medium post](https://medium.com/@ryanhaining/leading-typename-dot-template-and-why-they-are-necessary-43e56e311f48)

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all, of your compilation errors are due to the types in your base class not being examined during name lookup of your derived class. The C++ standard says that you should fully qualify the type names (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template)). In other words, the types in your template base class are not visible from your derived class without their being fully qualified. Below is a simple example that compiles and runs with `g++-6.3.0 -std=c++14`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename S = deque<T> >
class Base
{
public:
    typedef typename S::size_type size_type;

    virtual size_type size() = 0;
};


template <typename T, typename S = deque<T> >
class MyClass : public Base<T, S>
{
public:
    // type name has to be fully qualified
    typedef typename Base<T,S>::size_type size_type;

    // you could use "typename Base<T,S>::size_type" here instead
    size_type size() override { return 0; }
};


int main()
{
    MyClass<int> c;
    cout << c.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: `typedef typename Base<T,S>::size_type size_type;` can be accomplished with `using typename Base<T,S>::size_type;`

Comment: Yes, all of the `typedef`s can be accomplished with `using` (alias declarations), and I prefer to use alias declarations instead of `typedef`. However, I decided to leave the `typedef`s to make the example closer to Fantasy_RQG's original code.

Comment: your code works great , but I can't split function define into declaration and definition. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: To split the function declaration from the definition, first leave the definition inside the class. It will look like this: `size_type size() override;` Then, after the class or in the `.C` file: `template <typename T, typename S>
    typename MyClass<T,S>::size_type MyClass<T,S>::size()
    {
        return 0;
    }` You can write the definition on different lines, of course. If you want me to edit the code in the answer to reflect this let me know.

Comment: BTW if you place the template definition in a `.C` or `.cpp` file, you'll need to explicitly instantiate the template class for particular types, which is restricting (and a different subject). I usually just place the definitions in `.h` files.