# Unable to import of typedefs from template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef, using

*This question is not duplicate but follow up of* [Propagating 'typedef' from based to derived class for 'template'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template)

As a solution to inheriting of the typedefs,  it was suggested to use `using` to import them to derived class, whereas simple `using typename Base::typedefed_type`is supposed to suffice.

The following code is mostly taken from [Roman Kruglov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410690/2466685):

```
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> Vec_t;
};


template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    using typename A::Vec_t;
    // .........

private:
    Vec_t v;
};

int main()
{
B<int> bb;
}
```

However it  fails to compile, because compilers badly want template arguments of `A`.

Intel compiler error message:

```
    1>C:\Work\EDPS\test_eigen\test_eigen.cpp(27): error : argument list for class template "A" is missing
1>      using typename A::Vec_t;
1>                     ^
1>          detected during instantiation of class "B<T> [with T=int]" at line 34
1>
1>C:\Work\EDPS\test_eigen\test_eigen.cpp(31): error : identifier "Vec_t" is undefined
1>      Vec_t v;
1>      ^
1>          detected during instantiation of class "B<T> [with T=int]" at line 34
1>
```

MVC Error message:

```
 c:\work\edps\test_eigen\test_eigen.cpp(27): error C2955: 'A': use of class template requires template argument list
1>c:\work\edps\test_eigen\test_eigen.cpp(17): note: see declaration of 'A'
1>c:\work\edps\test_eigen\test_eigen.cpp(32): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'B<T>' being compiled
1>c:\work\edps\test_eigen\test_eigen.cpp(27): error C3210: 'A': a member using-declaration can only be applied to a base class member
1>c:\work\edps\test_eigen\test_eigen.cpp(32): warning C4624: 'B<int>': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
```

So what's wrong? Am I missing something? Or are perhaps the comments and answers there wrong??

Comment: `using typename A<T>::Vec_t;`

Comment: The compiler errors are really straightforward: you are using `A` without an argument list where it's required.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `A` is a template so you need `A<T>`

Comment: I would argue that is not a typo. a typo is something the author knew but mistyped. Here I think the author did not realize typename A and typename A<T> are different.

Comment: Anybody made the effort to read the linked thread?? The whole question arose because it was suggested that  `using typename A::Vec_t;` should suffice. The code is also copied from there.

Comment: @AndreyPro I don't see where such a thing was **suggested**.

Comment: @Nelfeal, I think that from the second answer in that link.

Comment: @AndreyPro The answer is wrong.  I left a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template#comment93240588_52410690)

Comment: also explicitly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template#comment15998323_1643035

Comment: Well, both GCC and Clang in C++17 want the full qualification (`<T>`), so I'd say both [Johan Lundberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template#comment15998323_1643035) and [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template#comment1518402_1643190) are wrong. I see why, though: if the base class is a full specialization (`A<int> for example), then you don't need the argument list, because in this case, you do have the injected class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion arises from the way `A` is used as a base class. If a class template derives from a class template with a template argument, you have to fully qualify the base class name. But if a class derives from a class template specialization, you can use the base class name without a template argument list.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    using t = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    using typename A<T>::t; // Full qualification needed -> mandatory argument list
};

struct C : A<int> {
    using typename A::t; // Injected class name -> optional argument list
};
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6baf4d82838192d)

Also, note that `t` is available in `C` directly, without any using declaration or typedef. I may still be useful, for example if `C` inherits from `A<int>` privately, but you want `t` to be available publicly in `C` (in the example, `C` inherits publicly by default because it is a `struct`).

Answer (score 2):

Just modify it as this

```
template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    using typename A<T>::Vec_t;
    // .........

};
```

In C++, if `A` is a template, standalone `A`  is not a 'complete' type. You need to specify the template argument. That is why `A<T>` solves it.

Comment: Downvoting for an answer to a low quality question. Instead, it should be a comment with VTC as a 'typographical error'

Comment: @AndreyPro I understood what's asked very well, thank you.

Comment: Btw it's not about `typename A`, it's about `A`.