# typedef inheritance from a pure abstract base

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, typedef, template-method-pattern

Edit: Found  [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/typedef-in-template-base-class)

I've whittled down some problem code to the simplest working case to illustrate the following: my typedef in a pure abstract base class is not being inherited by the derived class. In the code below I'd like to inherit the `system_t` typedef into the `ConcreteTemplateMethod`:

```
#include <iostream>

// pure abstract template-method
template <typename T>   // T == Analyzer<U>
class TemplateMethod {
  public:
    typedef T system_t;

    virtual void fn (const system_t& t) const = 0;
};


template <typename T>
class Analyzer {
  public:
    void TemplatedAlgorithm (const TemplateMethod< Analyzer <T> >& a) const {
      printf ("Analyzer::TemplatedAlgorithm\n");
      a.fn(*this);  // run the template-method
    }

    void fn () const {
      printf ("Analyzer::fn\n");
    }
};


// concrete template-method
template <typename T>
class ConcreteTemplateMethod : public TemplateMethod < Analyzer<T> > {
  public:
    typedef Analyzer<T> system_t;

    virtual void fn (const system_t& t) const {
      printf ("ConcreteTemplateMethod::fn\n");
      t.fn(); // perform Analyzer's fn
    }
};

int main () {

  Analyzer <double> a;
  ConcreteTemplateMethod<double> dtm;
  a.TemplatedAlgorithm(dtm);

  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs as expected. In the `ConcreteTemplateMethod` the following is required, and when removed causes compiler errors:

```
typedef Analyzer<T> system_t;
```

Note that the `system_t` type is already `typedef`'ed in the base class, however. Why must I include another typedef when inheriting?

I realize that I can qualify the typename of `system_t` in the derived `ConcreteTemplateMethod` by using `typename TemplateMethod< Analyzer<T> >::system_t&`, but that's a bit verbose, and I'd like to avoid having to re-`typedef` to the base everytime I inherit and need to use that same `system_t`. Is there a way around this that I can define in the base `TemplateMethod`?

Comment: no, you cannot do that directly.
you can however make up a macro which will do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance and templates in C++ - why are methods invisible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Propagating 'typedef' from based to derived class for 'template'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should do

```
typedef typename TemplateMethod<X>::system_t system_t;
```

to "inherit" typedef.  typedef is not automatically inherited (if compiler is compliant).

if you look through stack overflow, there will be duplicate of this question somewhere.