# Is this name lookup in dependent base class with VC++ 2010 non-standard?

Tags: c++, templates, base-class, class-members, name-lookup

The code below does not compile on Ideone or Codepad, yielding errors like:

> 'X' was not declared in this scope

but it does on VC++ 2010:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <typeinfo>

    template<typename T>
    struct Base
    {
            typedef T X;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Derived
    :
            Base<T>
    {
            static void print()
            {
                    std::cout << typeid(X).name() << "\n";
            }
     };

    int main()
    {
            Derived<int>::print();
            Derived<char>::print();
            Derived<float>::print();
            return 0;
    }
```

where it prints `int`, `char` and `float`. Should I change my code to:

```
    template<typename T>
    struct Derived
    {
            typedef Base<T> B;
            static void print()
            {
                    std::cout << typeid(typename B::X).name() << "\n";
            }
     };
```

in order to be standard-conforming?

Comment: Did you mean to drop the inheritance in the second example?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I meant to drop it, because the example was from a real project where `Base` depends on many more template parameters, so that an inner `typedef` makes the code a little more readable. Readability was actually why I tried the inheritance in MSVC++, but it failed on g++.

Comment: Same answer as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908248/using-this-keyword-in-destructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant the equivalent of this (note you have dropped the inheritance in your example):

```
template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>  {
  static void print() {
    std::cout << typeid(typename Base<T>::X).name() << "\n"; 
  }
};
```

then yes, that is standard compliant code. But note that the result of `typeid(some type).name()` is implementation dependent. On GCC your main produces `i`, `c` and `f`.

Answer (score -1):

$ g++ -Wall test.cpp
test.cpp: In static member function 'static void Derived::print()':
test.cpp:15:37: error: 'X' was not declared in this scope

$ g++ --version
g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.6.2

Comment: Can you give some context as to what this means, and how it's relevant to the question?