# Why does the child class not see the parent's typedef struct in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, name-lookup

I ran across some C++ code recently that `typedef`ed a `struct` in a parent class. However, it seemed to be unavailable in the child class, even tho it was not marked `private` (it was `protected`). I've created a minimal working example (below) below that demonstrates this failure. I have turned everything public and it still fails. The error that is given is (using `g++`):

```
B.h:8: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
B.h.8: error: ISO C++ forbids declartion of 'Datum' with no type
```

#### A.h (compiles)

```
template<typename S, typename T> class A {
public:
    typedef struct {
        S x;
        T y;
    } Datum;
};
```

#### B.h (does not compile)

```
#include "A.h"
template<typename Q> class B : public A<Q, Q> {
public:
    void output(const Datum& dat);
};
```

#### B.h (compiles)

```
#include "A.h"
template<typename Q> class B : public A<Q, Q> {
public:
    typedef struct {
        Q x;
        Q y;
    } Datum;
    void output(const Datum& dat);
};
```

Why does the first version of `B.h` not compile? Is the second one a safe alternative? Is there a better (more concise or idiomatic) way to handle this?

Comment: I'm confident that `A.h` does *not* compile as written.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you. I am in a situation where I cannot copy and paste, so I made an error in it. Fixed now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Propagating 'typedef' from based to derived class for 'template'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template)

Comment: @BoPersson the answers turn out to be related, but I would say the question is not duplicate because if I had known how closely related that question was, I probably would have known my solution already. I.e. I'd say the answers are similar but the questions are different.

Comment: @Kazark - That's a matter of opinion. :-) There are lots of questions about why names from templated base classes are not visible - all for the same reason. The linked to question  has the `typedef` in common with this, but the problem is general.

Comment: @Kazark Because your question is not gcc-specific, I have removed this tag. And I have added [tag:name-lookup] also.

Comment: @BoPersson Do we need a dependent-base-class tag?

Comment: Same underlying issue: [In a templated derived class, why do I need to qualify base class member names with “this->” inside a member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908248/in-a-templated-derived-class-why-do-i-need-to-qualify-base-class-member-names-w/7908530#7908530)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
typedef struct {
    S x;
    T y;
}
```

is ill-formed. `typedef` needs a type and an "alias" to name that type. What you probably need is

```
template<typename S, typename T> 
class A {
 public:
    struct Datum { S x; T y; };
};
```

without the typedef, which is not necessary at all here. Then, you need to qualify the `Datum` name properly, as `typename A<Q,Q>::Datum`:

```
#include "A.h"
template<typename Q> 
class B : public A<Q, Q> {
 public:
    void output(const typename A<Q,Q>::Datum& dat);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to say `typename A<Q,Q>::Datum` inside `B`. Since the base is a template, its names are dependent names and not visible during the first phase, and you need `typename` to specify that the name names a type (and not a value or a template).

You should also lose the `typedef`. C++ works differently from C, and you should say:

```
struct Datum { S x; T y };
```

Comment: You need to throw in a `typename` too.