# Compiling issues when deriving from a class nested in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, g++4.8

I am writing template class for a sudoku puzzle, where the template parameters define the size of the rows and columns. I am using g++-4.8 with C++11 enabled.

I have one compiling issue that I worked around, but I would like to understand why it is not working as expected:

My RowIteratorImpl class derives from VirtualLineIteratorImpl, but I cannot access its fields virtualLineIdx and cellInVirtualLineIdx although this should be possible:

```
    class VirtualLineIteratorImpl : public CellIteratorImpl
    {
    protected:
        size_t virtualLineIdx;
        size_t cellInVirtualLineIdx;

    public:
        VirtualLineIteratorImpl(size_t virtualLineIdx)
            : virtualLineIdx(virtualLineIdx), cellInVirtualLineIdx(0)
        {}

        virtual void increment(size_t offset)
        {
            virtualLineIdx += offset;
        }
    };

    class RowIteratorImpl : public VirtualLineIteratorImpl
    {
    public:
        using VirtualLineIteratorImpl::VirtualLineIteratorImpl;

        virtual size_t getCellIdx() const 
        {
            // TODO: does not compile
            // return mivTSudoku::getCellIdxInRow(virtualLineIdx, cellInVirtualLineIdx);
            return mivTSudoku::getCellIdxInRow(VirtualLineIteratorImpl::virtualLineIdx, VirtualLineIteratorImpl::cellInVirtualLineIdx);
        }
    };
```

The compiler generates the following message:

mivSudoku.h: In member function ‘virtual size_t mivTSudoku::RowIteratorImpl::getCellIdx() const’:
mivSudoku.h:85:39: error: ‘virtualLineIdx’ was not declared in this scope
    return mivTSudoku::getCellIdxInRow(virtualLineIdx, cellInVirtualLineIdx);

This is the entire class definition:

```
#ifndef MIVSUDOKU_H
#define MIVSUDOKU_H

#include <bitset>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

template<size_t n, size_t m=n>
class mivTSudoku
{
public:
    class Cell
    {};

    static constexpr size_t getCellIdx(size_t rowIdx, size_t colIdx) 
    {
        return rowIdx * dim + colIdx;
    }
    static constexpr size_t getCellIdxInRow(size_t rowIdx, size_t cellInRowIdx) 
    {
        return getCellIdx(rowIdx, cellInRowIdx);
    }
    static constexpr size_t getCellIdxInColumn(size_t columnIdx, size_t cellInColumnIdx) 
    {
        return getCellIdx(cellInColumnIdx, columnIdx); 
    }
    static constexpr size_t getCellIdxInBlock(size_t blockIdx, size_t cellInBlockIdx) 
    {
        return getCellIdx((blockIdx / n) * n + (cellInBlockIdx / m), (blockIdx % n) * m + (cellInBlockIdx % m)); 
    }

    class CellIteratorImpl
    {
    public:
        virtual CellIteratorImpl* clone() = 0;
        virtual void increment(size_t) = 0;
        virtual void getCellIdx() const = 0;
    };

    class AllCellIteratorImpl : public CellIteratorImpl
    {
    private:
        size_t m_cellIdx;

    public:
        AllCellIteratorImpl()
            : m_cellIdx(0)
        {}

        virtual void increment(size_t offset)
        {
            m_cellIdx += offset;
        }
        virtual void getCellIdx() const 
        {
            return m_cellIdx;
        }
    };

    class VirtualLineIteratorImpl : public CellIteratorImpl
    {
    protected:
        size_t virtualLineIdx;
        size_t cellInVirtualLineIdx;

    public:
        VirtualLineIteratorImpl(size_t virtualLineIdx)
            : virtualLineIdx(virtualLineIdx), cellInVirtualLineIdx(0)
        {}

        virtual void increment(size_t offset)
        {
            virtualLineIdx += offset;
        }
    };

    class RowIteratorImpl : public VirtualLineIteratorImpl
    {
    public:
        using VirtualLineIteratorImpl::VirtualLineIteratorImpl;

        virtual size_t getCellIdx() const 
        {
            // TODO: does not compile
            //return mivTSudoku::getCellIdxInRow(virtualLineIdx, cellInVirtualLineIdx);
            return mivTSudoku::getCellIdxInRow(VirtualLineIteratorImpl::virtualLineIdx, VirtualLineIteratorImpl::cellInVirtualLineIdx);
        }
    };

    typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag CellIterator_tag;
    typedef std::iterator<CellIterator_tag, Cell> CellIteratorBase; 
    class Cellterator : public CellIteratorBase
    {
    private:
        typedef CellIteratorBase baseclass;

    protected:
        mivTSudoku* pSudoku;
        CellIteratorImpl* m_pIterImpl;

    public:
        Cellterator(mivTSudoku* pSudoku, CellIteratorImpl* impl) noexcept
            : pSudoku(pSudoku), m_pIterImpl(impl)
        {
        }

        ~Cellterator()
        {
            delete m_pIterImpl;
            m_pIterImpl = nullptr;
        }

        Cellterator(const Cellterator& rhs) noexcept 
            : pSudoku(pSudoku), m_pIterImpl(rhs.m_pIterImpl->clone())
        {}

        Cellterator(Cellterator&& rhs) noexcept
            : pSudoku(pSudoku), m_pIterImpl(rhs.m_pIterImpl)
        {
            rhs.m_pIterImpl = nullptr;
        }

        Cellterator& operator=(const Cellterator& rhs) noexcept
        {
            if (this == &rhs) return *this;
            this->pSudoku = rhs.pSudoku;
            this->m_pIterImpl = rhs.m_pIterImpl->clone();
        }

        Cellterator& operator=(Cellterator&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            if (this == &rhs) return *this;
            this->pSudoku = rhs.pSudoku;
            this->m_pIterImpl = rhs.m_pIterImpl;
            rhs.m_pIterImpl = 0;
        }

        size_t getCellIdx() const 
        {
            return m_pIterImpl->getCellIdx();
        }

        typedef typename baseclass::reference reference;
        reference operator*()
        {
            return pSudoku->m_field[getCellIdx()];
        }

        reference const operator*() const
        {
            return pSudoku->m_field[getCellIdx()];
        }

        typedef typename baseclass::pointer pointer;
        pointer operator->()
        {
            return pSudoku->m_field + getCellIdx();
        }

        pointer const operator->() const
        {
            return pSudoku->m_field + getCellIdx();
        }

        Cellterator& operator++()
        {
            m_pIterImpl->increment(1);
            return *this;
        }
        Cellterator operator++(int)
        {
            Cellterator iter;
            this->operator++();
            return iter;
        }       
        bool operator==(const Cellterator& rhs) const
        {
            return getCellIdx()==rhs.getCellIdx();
        }
        bool operator!=(const Cellterator& rhs) const
        {
            return !operator==(rhs);
        }
    };

public:
    static const size_t dim = n*m;
    static const size_t ncells = dim*dim;

private:
    Cell m_field[dim];
};


typedef mivTSudoku<3,3> mivSudoku;



#endif // MIVSUDOKU_H
```

Can some explain to me why?

Comment: Does the following question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908248/in-a-templated-derived-class-why-do-i-need-to-qualify-base-class-member-names-w

Comment: One advise: Don't use tabs to indent code in markdown, use 4 spaces

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Using the this->pointer fixed the issue. I will now find some time to read it and completely understand everything. Very usefull post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that names not depending on a template argument are looked up only when the template arguments are not known. Since your base class depends on a template argument (implicitly by being nested inside a template) the compiler diesn't look at the base class, yet: until the template is instantiated it could get specialuzed, resulting in a completely different class.

The fix is to make the reference to the base member depend on the template argument, e.g., by using `this->virtualLineIdx`.

Comment: Thank you. If you want to have a more detailed answer, have a look at the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908248/in-a-templated-derived-class-why-do-i-need-to-qualify-base-class-member-names-w) giving by nosid.