# When to use "this" pointer in member function

Tags: c++, this

**Background:**

I am reading code written by someone else, and I am fairly new to C++ programming. When I look at the classes written by that person, and the corresponding member functions, I get confused with the usage of the `this` pointer. In some member functions `this` is used and in others not.

Why is that the case?

I know it is a very common confusion for the ones who start doing C++ recently.

**Code Snippets:**

*The class:*

```
class InitTable {
public:
    InitTable();
    virtual ~InitTable();

    void clearTable();
    void addEntry(std::string sumoID);
    void deleteEntry(std::string sumoID);
    InitEntry* getEntry(std::string sumoID);
    IPv4Address getEntryIPaddress(std::string sumoID);

protected:
    std::map<std::string, InitEntry*> table; 
};
```

*Member function (with `this`):*

```
void InitTable::clearTable()
{
    this->table.clear();
}
```

*Member function (without `this`):*

```
void InitTable::deleteEntry(std::string sumoID)
{
    InitEntry* ie = getEntry(sumoID);
    if (ie != NULL)
    {
        table.erase(sumoID);
        delete ie;
    }
}
```

---

**Question:**

Note that in `void InitTable::clearTable()` , `this->table.clear()` is used and in `void InitTable::deleteEntry()`, `table.erase()` only `table` without `this` is used.

```
void InitTable::clearTable()
{
    table.clear();    // no "this"
}
```

What is the trick in here? What would be the behaviour if `this->table.erase()` would be used instead.

```
void InitTable::deleteEntry(std::string sumoID)
{
    InitEntry* ie = getEntry(sumoID);
    if (ie != NULL)
    {
        this->table.erase(sumoID);   // "this" added
        delete ie;
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm a bit of n00b so a thorough description with minimal example would be very helpful.

Comment: Unless the use of `this` resolves a name clash (if the member is shadowed by, say, a function parameter), it is mostly a matter of taste.  Personally, I always `this`-qualify member access.  There may be good reasons to do the opposite but using one style consistently is almost certainly a good idea.

Comment: so basically in this case both ways would be fine with `this` and without it?

Comment: Yes, the `this` is not required here, except by personal taste, perhaps.

Comment: `this` can also be used if you're returning a reference of the calling object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never required inside a normal function, unless there is a parameter with the same name as a member. In a constructor you can use an initalizer list to prevent ambiguity. The use of a `this` pointer might be required when you use templates.

Comment: The most common reason to use `this` is to pass in to other functions where you need "pointer to this object". JavaScript, by contrast, insists on requiring this.

Comment: What if the class is of a template class? You can use `this->x` to make the expression dependent on the template types.

Comment: *never required* is not quite true. It is required when you're referring to a member of a base class template for instance.

Comment: _"... unless there is a parameter with the same name as a member"_ In the member initializer list of a constructor, the (parameter) names can be used unambiguously.

Comment: For expansion on Praetorians and rodrigos comments I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908248/in-a-templated-derived-class-why-do-i-need-to-qualify-base-class-member-names-w