# Problems encountered in writing abstract classes and derived classes

Tags: c++, abstract-class

When I was implementing a data structure, I encountered the following problem of use of undeclared identifier 'a'. Isn't an inherited from the base class? Why can't I access it?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
template <typename T> class A {
public:
  T a;
  virtual void show() = 0;
};

template <typename T> class B : public A<T> {
public:
  B() { a = 0; }
  void show() { std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; }
};
```

But when I added the this pointer, there was no error message：

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
template <typename T> class A {
public:
  T a;
  virtual void show() = 0;
};

template <typename T> class B : public A<T> {
public:
  B() { this->a = 0; }
  void show() { std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; }
};
```

Why???

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908248/in-a-templated-derived-class-why-do-i-need-to-qualify-base-class-member-names-w)

Comment: Or  this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1121016/4123703 and [C++ faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `this->a`, you are explicitly telling the compiler to look for the member `a` in the scope of the current instance. This helps the compiler resolve the name correctly, even in the context of templates with potential scope ambiguities.

In your first example;

```cpp
B() { a = 0; }
```

The compiler encounters `a` in the constructor of class `B`, and it's trying to find `a` within the scope of class `B`. However, since `a` is inherited from class `A<T>`, it's considered a dependent name and requires using `this->` to indicate the correct scope.

In your second example;

```cpp
B() { this->a = 0; }
```

You are explicitly using `this->a` to indicate that `a` is a member of the current instance. This resolves the scope ambiguity and lets the compiler know that `a` is inherited from the base class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that I don't know much about nondependent-name-lookup-members.