# Why do I need to use scope resolution in template inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

If I work with classes, everything is just fine:

```
struct Base1 {
  int value;
  Base1(int value) : value(value) { }
};

struct Test1 : public Base1 {
  int getValue() { return value; }  
  Test1(int value) : Base1(value) { }
};
```

but with templates scope resolution is needed:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base {
  T value;
  Base(T value) : value(value) { }
};

template <typename T>
struct Test : public Base<T> {
  typedef Base<T> parent;
  T getValue() { return parent::value; }  // why do I need to use parent:: here?
  Test(T value) : parent(value) { }
};
```

Without the scope resolution I receive error `'value' was not declared in this scope` (gcc compiler used).
Why?

Comment: What if you defined Test as follows: `struct Test<T> : Public Base<T>` ?

Comment: @Brady: then I receive an error `'Test' is not a template` - template must be created before it is specialized.

Comment: @Brady: The compiler would give you an error. The correct C++ syntax is the one used by OP.

Comment: For detailed explanation I like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7908530/546632)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance and templates in C++ - why are methods invisible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the compiler is not aware that `value` is dependent on the template argument.  As such, it attempts to resolve it during the first pass (prior to instantiating the template), and fails.

The two options are to use the scoping resolution, as you have, or use `this->value`.  Since `this` is always a dependent name, this will force the evaluation to occur during the second pass.

See http://ideone.com/07odY

Edit:  And as to the why it needs to be done at all:

While `Test<T>` derives from `Base<T>`, due to template specialization you could make `Base<std::string>` (for example) be totally different than the normal `Base<T>`, and not have a member named `value`, or it could be of a different type, or anything.  By forcing it to be a dependent name, the compiler is forced to wait until it knows the actual type involved before checking.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no other way to tell the compiler (since it is not defined within `Test`s body) that `value` is a dependent name. You are forcing the compiler to say that "Okay! Believe me when I say that there *is* such a member `value` for the type `T`."

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but I just love Douglas Adams! :)

Comment: And this is really cool, on my browser, you answered 42 seconds ago! :)

Comment: @Brady: LOL! Yeah, me too -- a huge fan of *the man*! Happy to be of any help, cheers!

Comment: Im going to have to dig that one out again, and try not to get my sofa stuck! All the good ones die young.

Comment: The first part of your answer is OK, but I don't see the relation with the CRTP here. `Test` inherits from `Base<T>`, not `Base<Test>`.

Comment: @Gorpik: Right you are. I should've said related.