# Why do I keep on getting a syntax error when using a base class typedef indirectly, when it's fine to use it directly?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, typedef

```
template<typename T>
struct self
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<class T>
class A
{
    struct Type { int x; };
};

template<class T>
class B1 : A<T>
{
    Type insert();     // OK
};

template<class T>
class B2 : self< A<T> >::type
{
    Type insert();     // syntax error? Why?
};
```

Comment: In conjunction with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template. Here's a working sample, the reason explained in the question link: http://ideone.com/Zk5vt

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance and templates in C++ - why are methods invisible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible)

Comment: @chris: I made an edit. That doesn't really seem to explain what's happening.

Comment: @Mehrdad, [ideone](http://ideone.com/4zH9W) gives an error for your OK line, and so does GCC 4.7.1.

Comment: @chris: So it's a bug in VC++?

Comment: @Mehrdad, I honestly wouldn't be surprised. It's clearly stated in the standard why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @chris: Ugh, it seems like something so basic that I *am* surprised a compiler would mess it up... although in their defense, I guess compilers don't have an obligation to reject invalid code... :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ has non-standard name lookup rules for templates; it's one of the three non-compliances they document [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx) (third paragraph).

I believe all lookups are deferred until the template is instantiated. At that time, all dependent names are available, and so the usual [`template` and `typename` keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245) and explicit member access are often not necessary; and this compiler doesn't bother to enforce them.

In both of your derived classes, `Type` is a dependent name and so must (when using a compiler that uses standard two-stage lookup) be qualified with `typename`:

```
 typename Type insert();
```