# Explicit template specialization & dependent name lookup problems

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a class that has some partial and explicit specialization. Having trouble with name lookup quirks though. Right now I have:

```
template <typename C, typename R>
class Command {
public:
    Command();

private:
void doTheDew() {
    /* ... */
}
};

template <typename C, typename R>
Command<C, R>::Command() {
    doTheDew();
}

template<typename R>
class Command<void, R> {
public:
    Command() {
        this->doTheDew();
    }
};

template<typename C>
class Command<C, void> {
public:
    Command() {
        this->doTheDew();
    }
};

template<>
class Command<void, void> {
public:
    Command() {
        this->doTheDew(); // 1
    }
};
```

On the line marked with "1" I get the error

```
class Command<void, void> has no member named doTheDew
```

I've tried quite a bit at this point and don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Each partial-specialization is its own class. You need to provide the respective definitions of `doTheDew`

Comment: Maybe I'm messing up terminology but the partial-specialization seem to work (I need the this dereference otherwise I got a name lookup error). It's only the explicit specialization that I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

It fails *immediately* in the line marked `// 1`, but it also fails **when instantiated** in both of the other specializations.

```
Command<int,void> c1; // fail
Command<void,int> c2; // fail
Command<int,int> c3; // OK
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5194ae0631e23bb0)

The reason is that none of the specialization has a `doTheDew()` method, as each specialization is its own class with its own members.

You might consider moving methods which should be available for the primary template and all the specializations to a base class. Don't forget to derive both the primary template and the specialization from that base then.

Answer (score 1):

As  0x499602D2 pointed out, templates are only that, templates to generate classes. So each template specialization is a different class. You need to provide the `doTheDew` declaration/definition in all of the specializations.

One way to reduce code duplication is to create a base class which provides the `doTheDew` method, and make all speciallizations inherit from it:

```
struct dothedew_impl
{
    void doTheDew();
};

template<typename C>
class Command<C, void> : public dothedew_impl
{
public:
    Command() {
        this->doTheDew();
    }
};
```

Of course if the `doTheDew()` method depends on some template parameter of the class, you could make the base class a template too:

```
template<typename T>
struct dothedew_impl
{
    void doTheDew();
};

template<typename C>
class Command<C, void> : public dothedew_impl<C>
{
public:
    Command() {
        this->doTheDew();
    }
};
```

Note that the `this->` in the last `Command()` implementation example is necessary, because [template dependent names are resolved during second template parsing phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible). The `this->` is used to force the compiler to include `doTheDev()` into the class scope, and move it to the first phase.