# C++ name resolution for member functions in template class

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct A {
    typedef T a; 
}; 
template<class T> 
struct B {
    typedef typename A<T>::a a;
    static a foo(a b); 
}; 
template<class T> 
a B<T>::foo(a b) {return b}

int main() {
    std::cout << B<int>::foo(1); 
}
```

Gives the following error: ([try it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed2b365d36906c68)).

```
main.cpp:13:1: error: 'a' does not name a type
    a B<T>::foo(a b) {return b}
```

An inline definition does not suffer from this error.

Could someone please explain why the compiler can not resolve `a` in this case, andhow I can make this code work.

I would like to not resolve all the names explicitly like

```
typename B<T>::a B<T>::foo(typename B<T>::a b) {return b}
```

As it would decrease readability.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible seem related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `a` here is still looking in global scope:

```
template<class T> 
a B<T>::foo(a b) {return b;}
^^
```

You're doing unqualifed lookup on `a`. Once you get to the `B<T>::` part of the definition, that scope is added to all further lookup. So the type of the argument `b` will be looked up in the scope of `B<T>`.

You simply need to qualify it the return type:

```
template<class T> 
typename B<T>::a B<T>::foo(a b) {return b;}
```

The relevant rules is for why the argument type `a` can be found is in [basic.lookup.unqual]/8:

> For the members of a class X, a name used in a member function body, in a default argument, in an exceptionspecification,
>   in the brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member (9.2), or **in the definition of a class
>   member outside of the definition of X, following the member’s declarator-id**, shall be declared in one of the
>   following ways:
>   — before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3), or
>   — shall be a member of class X or be a member of a base class of X (10.2), or

The return type `a` does not match the bolded text (or any of the text above), but the argument type `a` does.

Comment: The argument type isn't in the member function body. It is "in the definition of a class member outside of the definition of X, following the member’s *declarator-id*".

Answer (score 2):

If C++11 and 14, you can declare your function `auto` to get rid of the long return type. You need to specify it as a trailing type in C++11, but this allows you to get omit the `typename B<T>::` because the compiler already knows where to look.

```
//C++11
template<class T>
auto B<T>::foo(a b) -> a {return b;}

//C++14
template<class T>
auto B<T>::foo(a b) {return b;}
```