# How to use typedef from template base class in Ctor of the Derived?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

If I have a base and a derived class which are **both templates**:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    typedef T (*func)();
    Base(func f):m_f(f){};
    T invoke(){ return m_f();};
private:
    func m_f;
};

template <typename D>
class Derived : public Base<D> {
public:
    Derived(Base<D>::func f) : Base<D>(f) { };
    D foo() {
        return Base<D>::invoke();
    }
};
```

The derived class needs to pass a function pointer to the base in the **Ctor**. After reading [Inheritance and templates in C++ - why are methods invisible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible) I understand that the typedef in the Ctor should be called in the following manner:

```
Derived(Base<D>::func f) : Base<D>(f) {};
```

But then, when I try to compile:

```
int returnZero(){
    return 0;
}

Derived<int> d(returnZero);
std::cout << d.foo() << std::endl;
```

I get:

```
  error: expected ')' before 'f'
  Derived(Base<D>::func f) : Base<D>(f) { };
                        ^
cpp_code.cpp: In function 'int main()':
cpp_code.cpp:59:27: error: no matching function for call to 'Derived<int>::Derived(int (&)())'
  Derived<int> d(returnZero);
                           ^
cpp_code.cpp:47:7: note: candidate: constexpr Derived<int>::Derived(const Derived<int>&)
 class Derived : public Base<D> {
       ^~~~~~~
cpp_code.cpp:47:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int()' to 'const Derived<int>&'
cpp_code.cpp:47:7: note: candidate: constexpr Derived<int>::Derived(Derived<int>&&)
cpp_code.cpp:47:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int()' to 'Derived<int>&&'
```

What would be the proper way to use the function pointer (func) in the Ctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang as usually gives a very useful error message that explains everything:

```
error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'Base<D>::func'
    Derived(Base<D>::func f) : Base<D>(f) { };
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
            typename
```

If a dependent name is a type or template it should be disambiguated with a `typename` or a `template` keyword respectively.

This is needed because in the `Derived` definition the compiler doesn't know what type would be used instead of `D` and therefore it doesn't know what would be the actual definition of `Base<D>` due to possible specializations. That's why any identifier inside `Base<D>` is **dependent** on type `D`.

The compiler, however, still needs to be able to parse this code that it only partially understands, that's why you need to help it by telling that the identifier `func` is not just a member of `Base<D>`, but a `typename`, since that defines the context in which this identifier can be used.

---

*On a side note:* there is a [proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0634r0.pdf) to get rid of this annoying rule for the contexts where nothing but type can be used, such as yours.