# CRTP fails to inherit nested types and usings when derived type is itself a template?

Tags: c++, inheritance, inner-classes, crtp

I have the following code which works fine:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    using Bar = int;
};

struct Baz : public Foo<Baz>
{
    Bar bar;
};
```

Now I want to change Baz to accept a template parameter itself.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    using Bar = int;
};


template<typename T>
struct Baz : public Foo<Baz<T>>
{
    Bar bar;
};
```

This fails to compile in every compiler with `error: unknown type name 'Bar'`.  In fact, even if I put `using Foo<Baz>::Bar;` above that line, it still fails. (Yet the using itself compiles file!) Why?

Comment: Uh yeah I fail to see how the dupe has anything to do with what I asked..

Comment: `typename Foo<Baz<T>>::Bar bar;`

Comment: The dupe is better now, but if you don't want to do a `using`, you can simply do `typename Foo<Baz>::Bar bar;`.

Comment: Okay cool, that does compile, but my question wasn't how to solve this problem, my question was why?  What is it about the inclusion of a template that makes this code not compile?

Comment: @PaulAccisano - Then read the second duplicate I edited in. Types or variables make little difference here, neither does the syntax (`this->`) affect the explanation.

Comment: Ah, the second dupe does explain much better.  Thanks!

Comment: See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-inherited-members-invisible
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643035/propagating-typedef-from-based-to-derived-class-for-template