# Constraining parameter type in derived class to fit capabilities of base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, incomplete-type, class-template

I have a type `variant2` derived from `std::variant`. Now I want to be able to early capture potential assignment errors in case the assigned type doesn't match one of the variants types.

However, the way I came up with suffers from the issue that the `typedef` of the inner `std::variant` is incomplete until the closing braces, so I can't pass that through a concept. What alternatives do I have?

(Note: In production code the function assign is a lot more complicated, hence I want to be able to capture errors for the sake of user-friendliness early.)

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmm25oDGsJBApH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8dOE8SYrNe3D2bbZ2erzcH2CwB%2B90egK8ByObgIAE8EpgAPoEYhMQhXTY3SH/J4wl5wgBudTwhgIEIe9wImBYCQMtOBiORzDY%2BwAKqR9izGKwXgA1MkUqkfLwOfZ4BQo0nEcmCNFIzBHKyQml0hlMJlw3lsl5cnkaxlE466/kAOkt1x5Sr1%2ByFZBtrItlv2d2IwGxuLuYolUplwoVvLhBodcPdnst5p%2BON%2B%2B3j%2BxA%2BwSXgitDwyH2E3QIBA%2BAU2i8Zw6cOzuf9Cn5Ie5Ea9UetJgA7FZGwARFW/X60%2BnG5m2/mc7lm9kO%2BWU2P3U7nAj7WVjxXI16tyXSucUhfK46hwPj7C50neTeq6l3bua7Wm/vsjmi9HimdrwRmRPJ1PpzNlkCP8cggg5kAsAIyS1LS3LBAQ3I3jihzNnGCZeCkRiSgwITEAGcrrryS6zjuZj7juHZqncCaGj2Womm434bnCwSoeh87BtBchUiRTBeEQ%2BxMAoKTAAwECnBM%2BzMWYsScR68wwceJEkQAVAQCBSthdTgpsUkJk27aQm2hEnr84H7CwmJ8RJTZqfG35mKWf65qCRjWrKOkkbK5pcTxfFmPMOkaRwiy0JwACsvB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1hZssqxEv8PCkAQmg%2BYsADWID%2BRo%2BicJIQUpWFnC8AoIDZclIU%2BaQcCwDAiAoKg9J0NE5CUGgjX0DEwBcJsLRYMSGaYAKeCYAA7gA8qynCJTQtC0sQJUQBEBURMEdQIlNvArcwxAImNETaJU5WJW1bCCGNDC0OtFWkFgEReMAbhiLQJXcLwWCGUY4jXfgnxVMSmAvaFmCqJU7HrKF4FtAV6YRBiO0eFgBXongLAbYsVAGJ6Q2jRNjAbTIggiGI7BSAT8hKGoBW6C0BhGCgUWWPoeARCVkCLKgFxpC9AC02ZHK2piWNYZgaPs3NjQovCoP9xBylgrMQIsFRVM4ECuKMzSkIE0xFCU2TJKkAga/ruRpL0utzK07TVJMxvjG0h02905v9KUQzdHb7v1C7sylErsVrBIvkBfl13hRw%2ByqAAHLE3OxJI%2BzAMgmbdeaXD7BAuCECQhwJfMvDlVo8zpZl2V%2BRweWkKj/mSOakgAJyNvXGhNw3Tct/XpDBaF4fFaVSUpYs1V1csBAphBFD8Q1CRNcQoT8pw0ex/HifJ/sqeJZg%2BBEHLej8ITojiKT%2B/kyo6jXdTpAjRiCRozlHCBV3BXh2N7Hj/sqBUJHMdxwnScp5sNOGcPDtWiLnHq%2BcB4VWLqQBAXwsAxEVvfSuqNJD%2BXNFlEW9cRaYI0Nglo3cpZFVsP3QuqVSAZSyvfTYoce7ELITA8uZhaFEI4AXQeiwZYpGcJIIAA%3D)

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

template <typename T, typename Variant>
struct is_variant_type;

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Var, typename... Args>
struct is_variant_type<T, Var<Args...>>
    : public std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Args>...> {};

template <typename T, typename Variant>
concept variant_type = is_variant_type<T, Variant>::value;

template <typename T>
struct variant2 : public std::variant<std::monostate, int, T> 
{
    using inner_variant_type = variant2::variant;

    template <variant_type<inner_variant_type> U>
    auto assign(const U& arg) 
    {
        *this = arg;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    variant2<std::string> var;
    var.assign(2);
}
```

Yields:

```
<source>:19:42: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct variant2<T>'
   19 |     using inner_variant_type = variant2::variant;
      |                                          ^~~~~~~
<source>:18:8: note: definition of 'struct variant2<T>' is not complete until the closing brace
   18 | struct variant2 : public std::variant<std::monostate, int, T> {
      |        ^~~~~~~~
<source>:21:28: error: 'inner_variant_type' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'is_variant_type'?
   21 |     template <variant_type<inner_variant_type> U>
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            is_variant_type
```

etc.

Comment: Have you considered using composition instead of inheritance? It feels like it would address many issues.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I wanted to avoid forwarding the whole interface for std::variant. It worked quite well until now.

Comment: `std::variant` doesn't have a virtual destructor, and therefore inheriting from it might cause problems further down the road (if somebody will use `variant2` in a polymorphic way).

Comment: @wohlstad The risk is the same as inheriting from std::variant, however I do not add nonscalar fields so nothing to be done in virtual cleanup, it should be fine.

Comment: "I do not add nonscalar fields" It is still UB, regardless.

Comment: @n.m. How is this UB then? What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: It is UB because the standard says so, not because "there is nothing there to go wrong".

Comment: @n.m. You're of course right as I saw. Leaves the question why the committee decided to keep it UB, the base object could just be destroyed via normal destructor and done... But yeah, I will put  a word of caution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `typename` keyword, for the dependent type `variant2::variant`, in the alias declaration inside the class `variant2`.

Additionally, you have to mention which `operator=`, that you meant at the line `*this = var;`, which is by default not visible to the child. You can have more read here: [Inheritance and templates in C++ - why are inherited members invisible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-inherited-members-invisible)

```
template <typename T>
struct variant2 : public std::variant<std::monostate, int, T> 
{
    using inner_variant_type = typename variant2::variant;
    //                         ^^^^^^^^ ---> required 

    // required to mention, that the operator= is from the parent !!
    using std::variant<std::monostate, int, T>::operator=;  

    template <variant_type<inner_variant_type> U>
    auto assign(const U& var) {
        *this = var;
    }
};
```

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Peoh9fnYT)

Comment: That does it already! I'm pretty delighted that I don't even have to work around this, thanks! Btw you could also enter the dependent name to declare operator= like so: `using variant2::variant::operator=`; which is tad less verbose.

Comment: @glades Yes of, course. However, consider packing the `std::variant<std::monostate, int, T>` inside of your `variant2`, rather than inheriting. See [Is it okay to inherit implementation from STL containers, rather than delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate). This is also applied for `std::variant`.

Comment: I have considered that, but I have no additional nonscalar  fields inside my class so nothing to be done through a virtual destructor :) Also the class uses things like recursive nesting and idk if it can be done so easily via composition.