# Print boost::circular_buffer<T>

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I would like to make a template function to output the contents of a boost::circular_buffer. 
Here is the problematic piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const boost::circular_buffer<T>& cb){
   boost::circular_buffer<T>::const_iterator it;
   for(it=cb.begin(); it!=cb.end(); it++){
      os << it;
   }
   os << std::endl;
   return os;
}
```

The following error occurs:

```
need ‘typename’ before boost::circular_buffer<T>::const_iterator’ because ‘boost::circular_buffer<T>’ is a dependent scope
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you even read the error?

Comment: I think is as clear and instructive as C++ error messages get ;-)

Comment: It's one of those few templates errors that make you love the compiler for being so expressive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the error messages next time, what is wrong is pretty clear:

> **need ‘typename’ before boost::circular_buffer::const_iterator’** because ‘boost::circular_buffer’ is a dependent scope

So yeah, just do what the error message says:

```
typename boost::circular_buffer<T>::const_iterator it;
```

You can read about dependent names [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527849/how-do-you-understand-dependent-names-in-c).

Comment: Thx for the link about dependent names.