# typedef inside class - should it be complete

Tags: c++

Can i write code like this

```
class Foo
{
    typedef Foo type;
};
```

I don't see any limitations in standard about this.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Seems to me the compiler should tell you quickly enough whether it works...

Comment: @NateHekman compilers don't always follow all the rules.

Comment: `Foo` symbol exists, so you can `typedef` it, so yes it works.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Compiler: Apple GCC, OS: OSX 10.7

GCC finds nothing wrong with this, and I am able to use the type `type` later in the definition of Foo. However, you cannot use the type `type` outside of Foo.

Comment: Because `class` keyword means private by default. But if declared public, you can access with `Foo::type`.

Comment: @FredericS: Yes. Just making it clear that everything is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write that code. `type` and `Foo` are not reserved words, and C++ allows to define types within structs or classes. In fact, they are heavily used in templates for metaprogramming and type introspection.  See [How do you understand dependent names in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527849/how-do-you-understand-dependent-names-in-c) for further details on that aspect of the language.