# Template variable as unordered_map key, issue with iterator

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I try to use boost unordered_map with key as template variable.

```
 template<typename T>
std::string CPerformanceWatcher<T>::CheckPerformance(T &sOrderID, bool bDeleteRecord)
{
        boost::unordered_map<T, int>::iterator iter;
        iter = m_OrderIDTimeValMap->find(sOrderID);
        if(iter == m_OrderIDTimeValMap->end())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
}
```

But the compile complains with syntax error.
So my question is if I cannot use such an iterator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resolve the dependent name using `typename` keyword:

`typename boost::unordered_map<T, int>::iterator iter;`

See for more info on dependent names:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

[How do you understand dependent names in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527849/how-do-you-understand-dependent-names-in-c)