# What is all we need to know about C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Let's suppose that someone want to say: "*I've mastered all about the C++ templates*", what are all (or almost all) the knowledge, patterns and techniques related to templates that this person **should** know about?.

If someone wants to achieve this mastery, where he/she could look for all the "*mastering C++ templates*" topics?

Could you help me to create a complete recopilation of the C++ template-related topics, with links to examples and/or definitions for my own (and the community) future reference?

Since now, my own list of template-related stuff is the following:

- Knowledge

  - [Template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).
  - [Template template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213811/499359).
  - C++11 [Variadric templates](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates).

    - Argument packaging/unpacking.
  - [Function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/function-templates/info).
  - [Dependent names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527910/499359).
  - [Template argument deduction](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409).
  - C++14 [concepts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf).
- Techniques

  - [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE).
  - [Expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).
- Patterns

  - [CRTP](http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/).

But i suspect that i'm missing lots of things and even for the topics i've heard about i don't have tutorials/examples.

Comment: You can't say "I know everything about templates" unless you are lying or you are Stroustrup.

Comment: @H2CO3 - or Andrei Alexandrescu :)

Comment: Surely just list the contents of  David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis book?

Comment: @H2CO3 And what about Herb Sutter? o.o

Comment: http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/

Comment: For C++98, "C++ Templates - The Complete Guide" offers the most comprehensive coverage of the feature. Not sure if they are planning to publish a C++11 edition.

Comment: @h2co3 naw, Stroustrup has quite often talked about being surprised about what use people put templates to.  I doubt he would make that claim.

Comment: And if you want to claim to know everything about templates, you need to learn this by heart: *When writing a specialization be careful about its location, or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.* :P

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: They're [working on the next edition book targeting C++14](http://www.amazon.com/C-Templates-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0321714121/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). So hope it gets released sometime next year.

Comment: Isn't this a useful question for the community? I don't think this is opinion-based at all, i rather think that providing a list of template-related information could be pretty useful for any C++ coder.

Comment: Even if it's not opinion-based -- which I think it is -- you are asking for a *list of things*, which is also off-topic at Stack Overflow.  The closure of this question is not a commentary on how useful the question is.  Its a commentary on how on-topic it is for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JohnDibling so wich StackExchange will be the best to place a question like this one?

Comment: There is no StackExchange site where asking for a list-of-things is on-topic.  Sorry, but if you want to explore this topic here you'll need to narrow the focus.

Comment: @paperbirdmaster StackExchange does not seek to be the place where any question can be asked.  My guess would be none of them.  You could find one of many programming discussion forums elsewhere on the internet?