# Different behavior of Visual Studio and gcc when compiling variadic templates program

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I'm playing with C++11's variadic templates, and here is my code:

```
#include "iostream"
void func(){
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template< typename ...Params> void func(int x, Params... params){
    std::cout << " int " << x;
    func(params...);
}
template< typename ...Params> void func(float x, Params... params){
    std::cout << " float " << x;
    func(params...);
}
template< typename ...Params> void func(const char* x, Params... params){
    std::cout << " const char* " << x;
    func(params...);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    func(3.14f, 5, "Test");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The code above can be compiled and run on Visual Studio 2013 without any problem, but if I compile it with gcc 4.6.3 (I don't have gcc environment and using online service like [repl.it](http://repl.it)), this code will produce error like this:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void func(int, Params ...) [with Params = {const char*}]':
main.cpp:15:6:   required from 'void func(float, Params ...) [with Params = {int, const char*}]'
main.cpp:24:23:   required from here
main.cpp:11:6: error: no matching function for call to 'func(const char*&)'
  func(params...);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: void func()
 void func(){
      ^~~~
main.cpp:5:6: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
main.cpp:9:36: note: candidate: template<class ... Params> void func(int, Params ...)
 template< typename ...Params> void func(int x, Params... params){
                                    ^~~~
main.cpp:9:36: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:11:6: note:   cannot convert 'params#0' (type 'const char*') to type 'int'
  func(params...);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~

exit status 1
```

Whose behavior is right? Is this code has some problem I don't acknowledge or this is a bug of gcc?

BTW: If I change `func(3.14f,5,"test")` into `func(3.14f,5)` then gcc can compile this code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc behaviour is right.

Roughly speaking, when you instantiate a template, the instantiation needs to be legal C++ code *when placed where the original template definition was found*. (More precisely, all names except so-called [dependent names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527849/how-do-you-understand-dependent-names-in-c) need to be resolvable at the point of template definition).

In your case, the first template instantiates to an equivalent of

```
void func(int x, const char *params0){
    std::cout << " int " << x;
    func(params0);
}
```

and the last call is not valid *at the point of template definition*. Indeed, the template that can handle the call does not get declared until later in the code.

VC++ is known for its non-compliant handling of templates: it only checks validity of the instantiation *at the point of instantiation*, not at the point of the original template definition. This code illustrates it nicely.

To bring your code to compliance, first forward-declare the templates and then define them.

Comment: Note that this code does not compile on MSVC 19.11.25506 with the `/permissive-` flag.